# How to rectify the ORA 00907 error missing right parenthesis?

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
CREATE TABLE Attach_Files
(
    FileID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Files VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works in Microsoft SQL Server [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c063f5f083acfec6178676f49dec6c95)

It does not work in Oracle as it is a different RDBMS with different syntax and you need to fix the syntax errors on most lines:

- Identity columns need to be `GENERATED [ALWAYS|BY DEFAULT] AS IDENTITY [(other options)]`
- `NVARCHAR` should be `NVARCHAR2`
- `VARBINARY(MAX)` should be `BLOB`

You want:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Attach_Files
(
    FileID INTEGER
           GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
           NOT NULL,
    Name   NVARCHAR2(50)
           NOT NULL,
    Files  BLOB NOT NULL
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=24a6f71ae84ec0796277182b58f1c38b)*

Comment: Thank you, good explanation. I think you should define the "fileID" as INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 CACHE 50)

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation....

Answer (score 0):

That IDENTITY(1,1) looks more like SQL Server syntax.
For Oracle, use .. `IDENTITY START WITH a INCREMENT BY n`

Of course, can change a and n to the appropriate values for your case (a=1 and n=1).

Answer (score -2):

Try this statement:

```
    CREATE TABLE Attach_Files
(
    FileID INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
    (START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MAXVALUE 1000000
    CACHE 1
    CYCLE) NOT NULL,
    Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Files VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL
);
```

Thank you.

Comment: This will not work because the usage of VARBINARY is incorrect. Please see the already given correct answer by MT0

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation....